# Converting xml to html using Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xml, scrapy

I have pages like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<HTMLReturn xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://gccwebapps/PROWWS/">\r\n  <Result>OK</Result>\r\n  <ErrorMessageNewLine>\n</ErrorMessageNewLine>\r\n  <ErrorMessage />\r\n  <ID />\r\n  <HTML>&lt;div id=\'DivPROWContainer\' class=\'PROWContainer\'&gt;\n&lt;div id=\'DivTableGCCDocsHolder\' class=\'TableGCCDocsHolder\'&gt;\n&lt;table id=\'TableDisplayTable\' class=\'DisplayTable DisplayGCCDocsTable HtmlDataTable\'&gt;\n&lt;tbody&gt;\n&lt;tr class=\'DisplayTableHeaderRow HtmlDataTableHeaderRow DisplayTableTopRow\'&gt;\n&lt;th colspan=\'5\'&gt;Documents available for the planning Application&lt;/th&gt;\n&lt;/tr&gt;\n&lt;tr class=\'DisplayTableHeaderRow HtmlDataTableHeaderRow\'&gt;\n&lt;th&gt;Application Number&lt;/th&gt;\n&lt;th&gt;Plan number&lt;/th&gt;\n&lt;th&gt;Document type&lt;/th&gt;\n&lt;th&gt;Description&lt;/th&gt;\n&lt;th&gt;Date Entered&lt;/th&gt;\n&lt;/tr&gt;\n&lt;tr class=\'DisplayTableDataRow HtmlDataTableRow ResultRowAlternative\'&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;&lt;a id=\'AFormLink_APP_NO\' class=\'FormHyperLink\' href=\'https://ww3.gloucestershire.gov.uk/PROW/PROWWS.asmx/GetFileGCCContents?Filename=images%2f22_0001_NONMAT_DEC_LET.PDF\' data-DisableMeWhenSomethingChanged=\'1\' target=\'_blank\' rel=\'noopener noreferrer\'&gt;22/0001/NONMAT\n&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;Text&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;&lt;a id=\'AFormLink_DESCRIPTION\' class=\'FormHyperLink\' href=\'https://ww3.gloucestershire.gov.uk/PROW/PROWWS.asmx/GetFileGCCContents?Filename=images%2f22_0001_NONMAT_DEC_LET.PDF\' data-DisableMeWhenSomethingChanged=\'1\' target=\'_blank\' rel=\'noopener noreferrer\'&gt;Decision Letter\n&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;26/01/2022&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;/tr&gt;\n&lt;tr class=\'DisplayTableDataRow HtmlDataTableRow ResultRowAlternative\'&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;&lt;a id=\'AFormLink_APP_NO\' class=\'FormHyperLink\' href=\'https://ww3.gloucestershire.gov.uk/PROW/PROWWS.asmx/GetFileGCCContents?Filename=images%2f22_0001_NONMAT_APP_FORM_RED.PDF\' data-DisableMeWhenSomethingChanged=\'1\' target=\'_blank\' rel=\'noopener noreferrer\'&gt;22/0001/NONMAT\n&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;Plan&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;&lt;a id=\'AFormLink_DESCRIPTION\' class=\'FormHyperLink\' href=\'https://ww3.gloucestershire.gov.uk/PROW/PROWWS.asmx/GetFileGCCContents?Filename=images%2f22_0001_NONMAT_APP_FORM_RED.PDF\' data-DisableMeWhenSomethingChanged=\'1\' target=\'_blank\' rel=\'noopener noreferrer\'&gt;Application Form 9Redacted)\n&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;10/01/2022&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;/tr&gt;\n&lt;tr class=\'DisplayTableDataRow HtmlDataTableRow ResultRowAlternative\'&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;&lt;a id=\'AFormLink_APP_NO\' class=\'FormHyperLink\' href=\'https://ww3.gloucestershire.gov.uk/PROW/PROWWS.asmx/GetFileGCCContents?Filename=images%2f22_0001_NONMAT_LAND_PLAN_P20_2956_05D.PDF\' data-DisableMeWhenSomethingChanged=\'1\' target=\'_blank\' rel=\'noopener noreferrer\'&gt;22/0001/NONMAT\n&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;P20_2956_05D&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;Text&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;&lt;a id=\'AFormLink_DESCRIPTION\' class=\'FormHyperLink\' href=\'https://ww3.gloucestershire.gov.uk/PROW/PROWWS.asmx/GetFileGCCContents?Filename=images%2f22_0001_NONMAT_LAND_PLAN_P20_2956_05D.PDF\' data-DisableMeWhenSomethingChanged=\'1\' target=\'_blank\' rel=\'noopener noreferrer\'&gt;Landscape MasterPlan 04.01.22\n&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;10/01/2022&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;/tr&gt;\n&lt;tr class=\'DisplayTableDataRow HtmlDataTableRow ResultRowAlternative\'&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;&lt;a id=\'AFormLink_APP_NO\' class=\'FormHyperLink\' href=\'https://ww3.gloucestershire.gov.uk/PROW/PROWWS.asmx/GetFileGCCContents?Filename=images%2f22_0001_NONMAT_ELEC_SERV_190123_SC_XX_XX_DR_E_600.PDF\' data-DisableMeWhenSomethingChanged=\'1\' target=\'_blank\' rel=\'noopener noreferrer\'&gt;22/0001/NONMAT\n&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;190123_SC_XX_XX_DR_E_600&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;Plan&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;&lt;a id=\'AFormLink_DESCRIPTION\' class=\'FormHyperLink\' href=\'https://ww3.gloucestershire.gov.uk/PROW/PROWWS.asmx/GetFileGCCContents?Filename=images%2f22_0001_NONMAT_ELEC_SERV_190123_SC_XX_XX_DR_E_600.PDF\' data-DisableMeWhenSomethingChanged=\'1\' target=\'_blank\' rel=\'noopener noreferrer\'&gt;Electrical Services Site Wide\n&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;td&gt;10/01/2022&lt;/td&gt;\n&lt;/tr&gt;\n&lt;/tbody&gt;\n\n&lt;/table&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;\n&lt;div class=\'PROWDefaultFooter\'&gt;\n&lt;div class=\'PROWFooter1\'&gt;© 2014-21 Gloucestershire County Council, Shire Hall, Westgate Street, Gloucester GL1 2TG.\n&lt;/div&gt;\n&lt;div class=\'PROWFooter2\'&gt;&lt;STRONG&gt;Telephone:&lt;/STRONG&gt;+44(0)1452 425000 - &lt;STRONG&gt; Out of hours:&lt;/STRONG&gt; +44(0)845 6677788\n&lt;/div&gt;\n&lt;div class=\'PROWFooter2\'&gt;\n&lt;a id=\'AGCCLink\' class=\'GCCFooterLink\' href=\'http://www.gloucestershire.gov.uk\' data-DisableMeWhenSomethingChanged=\'1\'&gt;www.gloucestershire.gov.uk\n&lt;/a&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;\n</HTML>\r\n  <Script>gcc_docs_startScreenSetup();</Script>\r\n</HTMLReturn>
```

I need to find elements in it using xpath (without namespaces). I tried different variants, but I receive something very short and empty as an output (5-6 bytes):

That's the variants I tried. As you can see - none of them works.

```
import lxml.html as html
res = html.fromstring(sec_response.body)
len(res)
5
res.xpath('//div')
[]

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xhtml = ET.fromstring(sec_response.text)
len(xhtml)
6
xhtml.xpath('//div')
*** AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'xpath'

from lxml import etree
xslt_root = etree.XML(sec_response.body)
len(xslt_root)
6
xslt_root.xpath('//div')
[]

sec_response.selector.remove_namespaces()
sec_response.xpath('//td')
[]
sec_response.xpath('//tr')
[]
```

Please, show the way to transform it, so that xpath may be used to it (I need to look for //tr or //td or //a elements and FIND it).

Comment: See [this](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#removing-namespaces)

Comment: _"I need to find elements in it using xpath. So firsthand I need to convert it to html."_ -- Why do you think this is true (it's not)

Comment: 1) Upload a valid xml (as text) 2) Explain what do you need to extract from the xml 3) Explain what are the issues you are facing

Comment: @SuperUser I tried removing namespaces - looks like it does not work. ((( Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, sorry for not being too literal. I need to work with this data using xpath (without namespaces). Do you know the way to do it? Could you share it with me please?

Comment: @balderman I've uploaded the response.text - it is in the beginning of the question. I need to extract any data from it - links, descriptions, dates using xpath (without namespaces). I've removed picture and inserted text - showing what I'm trying to do and what wrong results I'm getting.

Comment: The text you have posted is not a valid xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
scrapy shell file:///....../temp.xml # your page's code

In [1]: response.xpath('//div')
Out[1]: []

In [2]: import html

In [3]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [4]: response.selector.remove_namespaces()

In [5]: text = html.unescape(response.text)

In [6]: sel = Selector(text=text)

In [7]: sel.xpath('//div')
Out[7]:
[<Selector xpath='//div' data='<div id="\\\'DivPROWContainer\\\'" class=...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div' data='<div id="\\\'DivTableGCCDocsHolder\\\'" c...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div' data='<div class="\\\'PROWDefaultFooter\\\'">\\n...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div' data='<div class="\\\'PROWFooter1\\\'">© 2014-2...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div' data='<div class="\\\'PROWFooter2\\\'"><strong>...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div' data='<div class="\\\'PROWFooter2\\\'">\\n<a id=...'>]
```